# How to get product price from json

Tags: python, json, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

With the following code I try to grab product information from a adidas api:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.adidas.com/api/plp/content-engine?"

params = {
    'sitePath': 'us',
    'query': 'women-athletic_sneakers'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
print(res)
data=res.json()
print(data)
for item in res.json()['raw']['itemList']['items']:
    print(item['displayName'],item['link'])
```

I can still extract some product information like `displayName` and `link` but I am not able to get any price information.

Comment: whats your question get price as you ggot link and display name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You try to find a `price` in the json, but there is no price information available.

### How to get the price?

You have to call another api with the `productId` per item:

```
requests.get('https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/'+item['productId'],headers=headers)
```

**Example**

```
import requests

url = "https://www.adidas.com/api/plp/content-engine?"

params = {
    'sitePath': 'us',
    'query': 'women-athletic_sneakers'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers=headers)
data=res.json()

for item in res.json()['raw']['itemList']['items']:
    itemRes = requests.get('https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/'+item['productId'],headers=headers)    
    print(item['displayName'],item['link'],itemRes.json()['price'])
```

**Output**

```
Ultraboost OG Shoes /us/ultraboost-og-shoes/GX5370.html 200 
Super Super Sleek 72 Shoes /us/super-super-sleek-72-shoes/GX2769.html 140 
Forum Mid Shoes /us/forum-mid-shoes/GW2857.html 150 
Forum Mid Shoes /us/forum-mid-shoes/GW2858.html 150 
Ultraboost 21 Shoes /us/ultraboost-21-shoes/FY0403.html 180 
Ultraboost 21 Shoes /us/ultraboost-21-shoes/FY0432.html 180 
Ultraboost 21 Shoes /us/ultraboost-21-shoes/FZ2762.html 180 
Ultraboost 21 Shoes /us/ultraboost-21-shoes/FY0402.html 180
```

Comment: but what about to get the sign of $ that also i want